# findViewById keeps giving me errors and a headache

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, syntax-error

**Hello all,**

I am new to Kotlin and was trying to keep recreating my code to get it easier for me to learn. i have created an dice app and it works. but everytime i create a new project and start. I always get the error on findViewById(R.id.) i make the layout first with all the ID`s assigned but no matter what i do i keep getting this error. I use Android Studio.
I hope someone can help me get this frustration out of my head.I want to know why it keeps getting that error. thanks in advance.

```
package com.example.dicedicebaby

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        //button action`
        val rollButton: Button = findViewById(R.id.button)
        
        //action of the button when pressed.
        rollButton.setOnClickListener{ stones()} 
    }
}

fun stones(){
    //The normal dice
    val fDice=Dice(6)
    //D20
    val dDice = Dice(20)
    //action of dice roll
   val dice = fDice.roll()
    //D20 action
    val secondDice = dDice.roll()
    //view
    val resultView: TextView = findViewById(R.id.dice)
    resultView.text = dice.toString()

    val secondView: TextView = findViewById(R.id.Ddice)
    secondView.text = secondDice.toString()
    


}

//makes the dice a dice.
class Dice(private val numSides:Int){

    fun roll():Int{
        return (1..numSides).random()
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the error? Also, please take a moment to properly format the code you attached, it's very hard to read as is.

Comment: Hello! We dont see the error like maybe you see it in the IDE, so please could you show us the error?, Another think that I see, its yor second Id (R.id.Ddice), is it the real name of your id of view in layout?

Comment: Hello all, thanks for the quick reply the code formatting went a bit of its rails I see a mod fixed it. Thank you. The error happens with the last 2 findViewById I have the text ID made to what I refer to. And even before I enter (R.id.Ddice) the findViewById gives me an error that it don't exist. I can post a screen shot or upload it to my github if that's more helpful. Maybe I'm just overlooking something I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggested approach is to migrate to [view binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding).
Plus, you should declare the `stones()` function inside the `MainActivity` class body:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        //action of the button when pressed.
        binding.rollButton.setOnClickListener{ stones() } 
    }

    fun stones(){
        //The normal dice
        val fDice=Dice(6)
        //D20
        val dDice = Dice(20)
        //action of dice roll
        val dice = fDice.roll()
        //D20 action
        val secondDice = dDice.roll()
        //view
        binding.dice.text = dice.toString()
        binding.Ddice.text = secondDice.toString()
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello. The binding syntax is for me unfortunately unformiliar. Because android studio is usually taking car of the first part ll go and try your solution as others tonight and will let you know thank you for the opportunity for me to learn